# NullPointerException on an int?

Tags: java, arrays, exception, int, nullpointerexception

is there anyone who can help me with this...

My code: http://pastebin.com/eD2WknXA

Crashes at the line 178 with a NPE

In the constructor of the class which the array is in, I even put a block of code which sets all the integers to 0, but even this didnt help?

anyone?

Comment: Can you show us some code to help debug the problem?

Comment: Post the code, that'll help diagnosis.

Comment: int cant be null. but int[] can be null. Have you considered that?

Comment: Sounds like you may not be initialising the actual member variable holding the array correctly in the constructor. i.e. a scoping issue. Do you have two variables with the same name by any chance?

Comment: Why are new users downvoted so quickly after 2-3mins? Give them a little time guys! Upvoted again for posting a comprehensible problem

Comment: The code is 300 lines, how can i paste that here

Comment: @Lukas The downvotes reflect that the question is poorly written. Hopefully, the question will be revised and the downvotes will be retracted, or even reversed.

Comment: @tweoi Just post the minimum amount of code that reproduces the error.

Comment: I dont think there's much to be left out with this problem, i guess ill put it on pastebin?

Comment: @tweoi: Check out my answer. These are the two options you have. Since from your pasted code, the array is of type `int[]`, it can't be an auto-unboxing issue. So your array itself is `null`

Comment: @Lukas Eder But how can my array be null if I initialized it with the new keyword and even set all of the values on 0?

Comment: Because of this statement: `cur = cur.children[i];` Somewhere, there is a bug

Answer (score 7):

You are very likely to have either

- An `Integer[]` with an `Integer` element being `null` (auto-unboxing)
- An `int[]`, which is `null` itself.

**EDIT**:

From your pasted code, it can only be the array `cur` itself, which is `null`. `root` cannot be `null`, because then the NPE would be on the previous line

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it's not using an `Integer` at some point, and auto-unboxing to int? For example:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Integer[] x = { null };

    // Automatic unboxing for each element
    for (int i : x) {
      System.out.println(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is line 178:

```
if (i == root.n-1 || val < cur.values[i] || cur.values[i] == 0) {
```

So either root is null, root.n is null or cur is null.  Put some debugging statements in to check the value of these references or watch them in a debugger.

Comment: The amount of children is 1 more then the amount of values in a node,
so it checks if the current value is the first one which is smaller then the first value in the given node, or if its the first empty one, or the last one

Comment: yep - i'm not going to look through your program's logic.  But if you're getting a NPE it's because you have a null reference and you have trying to call something on it e.g. method or instance variable.  If you just log the values somewhere or sit through in debugger you'll understand your code better and see what is null.

Comment: Lol, debugging statements, rofl. Set a breakpoint and check the variable values in the debugger.

Comment: @Angel O'Sphere I did state a debugger could be used.  But if the code is invoked in a loop with a lot of values or there are other issues where the debugger is tedious adding log statements to see what the variable is at each invocation doesn't sound such a funny idea.  So not sure why you're laughing so much.

Answer (score 1):

Can it be that your int array (not any element inside) is null?